# Android & JavaMail: send mail using cPanel's server

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, cpanel

I used javamail api for sending mails. First I tried gmail smtp servers and everything was ok. But now I want to use my own mail servers (via cPanel). But there is something wrong with my properties.  Can anyone help me?

Here is my properties code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "cpanel4.onofis.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

**And here is cPanel's server informations:**

**Username:**   blabllabla@blabla.com

**Password:**   blablablabla.

**Outgoing Server:**    cpanel4.onofis.com

**SMTP:** Port 465

**Authentication is required for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP.**

Comment: Test the settings in another mail client. Once you know they are working, use them in code. My guess is that "cpanel4.onofis.com" is incorrect. Did you supply credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I have found the problem. But still don't know why... I removed the SocketFactory lines and it's done.

The working code is this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "cpanel4.onofis.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Comment: A [common mistake](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).